# Google Maps JavaScript API with lit-element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, lit-element

I am trying to create a custom element with lit-html which uses the Google Maps API. How is it possible to make it work together?
Here is what I have so far:

**map-element.css:**

```
#map {
    height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
    width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**map-element.js:**

```
import {
    LitElement,
    html
} from '@polymer/lit-element';

class MapElement extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html `

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="map-element.css">

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>
            function initMap() {
                // The location of Uluru
                  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
                // The map, centered at Uluru
                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#map'), {zoom: 14, center: uluru});
                // The marker, positioned at Uluru
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initmap">
        </script>
    `;
    }


}
customElements.define('map-element', MapElement);
```

The output is just the placeholder for the div with map ID and I dont get any errors.

**Here is the reference for the code what I trying to use in my element:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Comment: Have you had a lokk at a working example with polymer ? https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map.html

Comment: that's a very outdated example, @PascalL. - OP is asking specifically about doing it inside a LitElement, which despite replacing PolymerElement in Polymer 3.0, is also available as its own separate Web Component - which is what the question shows. The syntax you linked to is no longer being used in modern Polymer at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can addScript in the `connectedCallback` method to be sure you include it when the component is included in the DOM

```
constructor() {
  this.callbackName = 'initMap';
  this.mapsUrl = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY
}
connectedCallback() {
  window[this.callbackName] = this._initMap.bind(this)
  this._addMapScript() // This
}

addScript: function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = `${this.mapsUrl}&callback=${this.callbackName}`;
  var s = document.querySelector('script') || document.body;
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

_initMap() {
  // To be we have shadow DOM ready.
  this.updateCompleted.then(this.initMap);
}

initMap() {
  // Your code here
}
```

Something like this should works

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API has a pretty severe bug where it persists until the page reloads: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821412

This creates problems in SPAs and web component frameworks like Lit, because the map is not contained by the component, it's attached to the window by event listeners.

Creating it is easy enough, though I'd add that you want to make sure that the API is only loaded once per page, so you need some kind of global log that you've already loaded it.

Something like this:

```
/** URI of the Maps JS library */
const googleMapsApi = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMapApi`;

/** Flag indicating that mapping library is currently being loaded, wait for it to . */
let mapLoading = false;

/** Flag indicating that mapping library has been downloaded. */
let mapReady = false;

// Set window level function for maps API to call back to
(window as any).initMapApi = function () {
    mapReady = true;
    delete (window as any).initMapApi;
}

/** Call this before calling maps API methods to make sure that it's loaded.
 *  @returns {Promise<boolean>} True once loaded. */
export async function mapApiLoaded() {
    if (mapReady)
        return true;

    while (mapLoading)
        await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);

    if (mapReady)
        return true;

    try {
        mapLoading = true;

        // Get the API key for the current user
        const google = // your key;
        if (!google)
            return;

        const mapApiUri = googleMapsApi.replace('API_KEY', google);

        // Add a <script> tag pointing to the API with the key
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script') as HTMLScriptElement;
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.onload = resolve;
            script.onerror = reject;
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            script.src = mapApiUri;
        });

        // Wait for the script to fire the callback method
        while (!mapReady)
            await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);

        console.log('️ API loaded.');
    }
    finally { mapLoading = false; }

    return mapReady;
}
```

Once you have that you can call it in each map component's `firstUpdated` or `connectedCallback`.

However, because of the memory leak if you create a lot of these maps and have a single-page application you'll rapidly hit an issue - every element that you pass to `new google.maps.Map` gets attached to the window until the user refreshes, and there's no way to disconnect it.

You can still use Google Maps API with an SPA, but you have to re-use map instances...

- On `connectedCallback` check for an existing map element and re-use if not connected.
- On `disconnectedCallback` clear routes/markers/etc and cache the map for reuse.

So your code ends up something like:

```
@customElement('map-element')
class MapElement 
    extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html `<div id="map"></div>`;
    }

    @query('#map')
    private mapWrapper: HTMLDivElement;

    private map: google.maps.Map;

    async connectedCallback() {
        await mapApiLoaded();
        
        const oldMap = window.oldMaps.pop() // Or however you get your previously used maps 
        if (!oldMap)
            // Create new map in your wrapper
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapWrapper, ...your options);
        else {
            // Reconfig old map and add it to your wrapper
            oldMap.setOptions(...your options);
            this.map = oldMap;
            this.mapWrapper.appendChild(oldMap);
        }
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        if(!this.map) return;

        // Remove from shadow DOM
        this.map.remove();

        // Clear markers/routes from this.map
        // Add to register of unused maps, say...
        window.oldMaps.push(this.map);
    }
}
```